# PHP method of replacing images within a word document

Tags: php, image, ms-word, border

I have a word document with numerous images making up a custom border.

Is there a way using PHP that I can programmatically replace all images within that word document with another image?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it using COM objects.
Docs :
fr2.php.net/com
drewd.com/2007/01/25/reading-from-a-word-document-with-com-in-php